# Vb.net search for file with in a directory

Tags: vb.net

So here is my Directory

```
Dim strFldCustom As String
strFldCustom = "W:\CUSTOM\130000"
```

I need to search for an excel file with in the sub folders of this directory and then open it. the excel file is called rptWESSSummary 132788-03-r1

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching By File Extensions VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676516/searching-by-file-extensions-vb-net)

Comment: I downvoted your question because it's a duplicate to many other questions on here and you showed no initiative to solve the problem on your own.  SO shouldn't be a place where you ask other people to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
System.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(string path)
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

to get an enumeration of all subdirectories, and then

```
System.IO.File.Exists()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

to check if that file exists.

You can open the file using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start

There are code samples in VB.Net at each of those links.

Note: If the file isn't in a folder *directly* under `strFldCustom`, but rather there could be folders with folders, you can use recursion to search the folders-in-folders for the file.

Comment: +1. You forgot to mention recursion for EnumerateDirectories.

Comment: @Neolisk: The question doesn't say *nested subfolders* ;-)  I'll update to mention that possibility.

Comment: You've executed the requirements flawlessly then. I just feel that OP may want to extend those as their next question... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here working basic code:

F parameter is the top directory where you want to scan system.GetfilesSystemEntries will take care to make the recursive job for you :)

In example you have to scan in windows folder you pass c:/windows and it will check into all nested, not nested, directory and return an array of string () which include the fullpath :) that's all

```
  Private Sub GetFile(ByVal f As String)
    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Scanning")
        Dim fList = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(f, "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(X) X.Contains("rptWESSSummary 132788-03-r1.xls"))
        Dim Z As String = String.Empty
        For Each el In fList
            Z = el.ToString
            Console.WriteLine(Z)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Load excel")
        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Z)
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Console.WriteLine("File aperto in excel")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Get all file with directory.GetFileSystemEntries create a new excel application accesso to the default workbooks and open your file.That's all :) hope it help