# VB * character not working

Tags: vb.net

I need my program to delete all bmp files in a directory, currently I have

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("*.bmp")
```

But it says the * is invalid, is the * not the right character to use in this context? if so, what is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching By File Extensions VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676516/searching-by-file-extensions-vb-net)

Comment: Remove the star and try again.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)

  For each f in fileEntries
       If file.GetExtension(f) = ".bmp" then
             file.deleteFile(f) 
       End If
  Next
```

I doing this from memory, but this should get you there.

you need to `import system.io` of course