# How can i open .exe file from the multiple folders in single click using vb.net or any other way?

Tags: vb.net

How can i open **.exe** file from the multiple folders in single click using vb.net or any other way?
tried using **process.start** method but it's not working properly and found error can't find path.
Example:

```
For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Application.StartupPath)
    Process.Start(Dir & "\" & "*.exe")
Next
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8676577/34092 will show you how to get the names of the `EXE` files. Then `Process.Start` them **one by one**.

Answer (score 0):

This will try to run all EXE files in the folder "myPath" and subfolders

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim pattern As String
        pattern = "*.EXE"

        Dim myPath As String
        myPath = "your Path"    ' Adjust to your needs

        Dim exeLst As IEnumerable(Of String)

        exeLst = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim sngFile As String
        For Each sngFile In exeLst
            Process.Start(sngFile)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```